# Como manipular objetos em uma Thread?

Tags: c#, thread, multithreading

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
MinhaClasse[] obj = new MinhaClasse[QtdUsuario];
Thread th;

For(int i = 0; i < QtdUsuario; i++)
{
    obj[i] = new MinhaClasse();

    th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Metodo));
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.IsBackground = true;
    th.Start(obj[i]);
}
```

Cada objeto mostra uma imagem na tela, e essas imagens ficam se movimentando na tela.

Ex: se o usuário definir a variavel `QtdUsuario` para `5` eu terei 5 objetos e cada objeto em uma thread. Então na tela eu terei 5 imagens se movimentando aleatoriamente.

Meu objetivo é:
Como posso identificar possíveis colisões entre esses objetos(imagens) ?
E como posso definir valores individuais para cada objeto ?
Ex: o usuário dirá que a imagem 1 terá `idade` = 5, e decrementa e ou incrementa
essa `idade` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste momento as suas threads nao tem informacao suficiente. 
Isto porque as threads necessitam de saber o estado dos objetos nas threads restantes (ou sejam elas necessitam de partilhar estado).

Pode nao ser óbvio, mas o estado que voce tem que partilhar é o array e ele **nao precisa de ser sincronizado**.
Já o acesso a cada elemento do array precisa, no momento em que consulta os objetos das outras threads.

Vou dar um exemplo, mas sem quaisquer garantias que pode ser útil no seu cenário:

```
public class Imagem{
    public Point Posicao{get; set;}

    public int Idade{get; set;}
}

public class Estado{
    public Imagem[] Imagens{get; set;}

    public Imagem MinhaImagem{get; set;}
}

var imagens = new Imagem[QtdUsuario];
//vamos assegurar que o array é inicializado antes de o passar como estado as threads
for(var i = 0; i < QtdUsuario; ++i){
    imagens[i] = new Imagem();
}

for(var i = 0; i < QtdUsuario; ++i){
    var thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Metodo));
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start(new Estado(){Imagens = imagens, MinhaImagem = imagens[i]});
}

private void Metodo(object parametro)
{
    Estado estado = parametro as Estado;

    //o lock está a ser feito perante o array
    //porque é necessário fazer lock por um objeto comum
    lock(estado.Imagens){
        //Verifica qual o estado das restantes imagens
        var algumaImagemNaPosicao = estado.Imagens
           .Any(img => img != estado.MinhaImagem && 
                img.Posicao.X == 10 && img.Posicao.Y == 2);

        if(!algumaImagemNaPosicao){
            //faz coisas com a imagem
            estado.MinhaImagem.Posicao.X = 10;
            estado.MinhaImagem.Posicao.y = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se calhar era melhor ter apenas uma thread. Como pode ver a maior parte do código tem sincronizacao e por isso nao terá proveito do paralelismo

Answer (score 1):

O delegate `ParameterizedThreadStart` possui a seguinte assinatura:

```
public delegate void ParameterizedThreadStart(object obj);
```

Isso indica que o seu método `Metodo` deverá segui-la, recebendo o estado como um `object`.

```
private void Metodo(object parametro)
{
   // Neste ponto já estamos em outra thread
   var paramMinhaClasse = (MinhaClasse) parametro;
}
```

Uma outra maneira de fazer seria passar diretamente um lambda como argumento na criação da Thread:

```
th = new Thread(() => Metodo(obj));
```

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49278/discussion-between-bruno-costa-and-meuchapeu).