# Criar instancia de classes em threads

Tags: c#, .net, thread

Imaginem que tenho uma classe:

```
Class Animal
{
    //Propriedades
}
```

Agora criando múltiplas instancias da classe faço da seguinte maneira:

```
Animal[] animais = new Animal[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    animais[i] = new Animal();
}
```

Até aqui tudo certo, em teoria ao fim da execução do método `for` eu terei um *array* com minhas 10 instancias da classe `Animal`.

Agora tenho o seguinte problema:

**Cada Animal deverá ser uma `Thread`.**

1 - Como posso implementar isto? para que cada instancia da minha classe seja uma `Thread`?

O que fiz, e não tenho certeza que está correto...

```
public void ThreadAnimal()
{
    Thread th;
    Animal[] animais = new Animal[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        animais[i] = new Animal();
        th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CriarAnimal));
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.IsBackground = true;
        th.Start(animais[i]);
    }
}

public void CriarAnimal(object obj)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        var animal = obj as Animal;
        var img = new Image()
        {
            Source = animal.Img,
            Tag = animal,
            Width = 32,
            Height = 32,
        };

        double posX = _canvas.ActualWidth - img.Width;
        double posY = _canvas.ActualHeight - img.Height;

        Canvas.SetLeft(img, rnd.NextDouble() * posX);
        Canvas.SetTop(img, rnd.NextDouble() * posY);

        _canvas.Children.Add(img);
    });
}
```

Cada `Thread` criada será uma instancia? ou cada `Thread` apenas está carregando uma referência de uma instancia?

2 - Imaginemos que a classe `Animal` tem uma propriedade `vida`, e quando a `vida` chegar a `0` o `Animal` deixa de existir ou seja minha instancia/*thread* são finalizadas/destruídas, como implementar isso?

Comment: O AO fez uma [pergunta muito semelhante anteriormente](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168404/como-manipular-objetos-em-uma-thread)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Instância de objeto é instância de objeto. *Thread* é *thread*. A não ser pelo fato que uma *thread* seja uma objeto específico, uma coisa não tem nada a ver com a outra.
2. *Threads* são finalizadas quando não estão mais sendo usadas (geralmente). Instâncias de objetos são destruídos quando não são mais úteis e o C# tem gerenciamento automático disto.

   Note que isso é um pouco mais complicado. O objeto que contém a *thread* pode ser coletado logo após dar o [`Start()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166032/101). Ele não é mais necessário depois que a *thread* entra em execução. Ela roda de forma independente.

   A *thread* propriamente dita existirá enquanto o que está contido dentro dela (`CriarAnimal`) estiver rodando. Note que ela pode rodar até mesmo com o encerramento "oficial" da aplicação, já que colocou em *background*.

Ao final o código apresentado criará um *array* com 10 animais onde cada um passará por algum processo de criação. Esse processo presume-se ser longo e os 10 poderão ocorrer em [paralelo e concorrentemente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166032/101), se der tempo :).

E é importante entender que [threads podem deixar o código mais lento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101) e não trazer ganhos, pelo contrário. tem grande chance do custo de criar uma *thread* ser maior que o custo de criar um `Animal`.

Entenda que é uma [técnica considerada quase obsoleta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101). O uso de tarefas pode ajudar um pouco minimizar o desperdício da criação de *thread*.

Veja mais ou menos como seria um [`for` paralelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169079/101).

Veja também: [Qual a diferença entre os async, multithereading, paralelismo e concorrência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157435/101).

Conforme os comentários abaixo, a pergunta foi modificada, e indica que essa solução parece menos adequada ainda.

Comment: Adicionei o método `CriarAnimal` na pergunta, a ideia seria que cada Animal seja uma `Thread`, para criar um ambiente de simulação para um trabalho sobre `Thread` da faculdade. O enunciado que tenho é `Os animais deverão ser implementados como Threads`.

Comment: Aí a pergunta começou mudar (e isso não é bom porque minha resposta começou ser invalidada). Implementar um `Animal` como *thread* não faz sentido conforme minha primeira afirmação. Tem criação de *thread* dentro da *thread* :-~.  A [resposta do Bruno Costa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168479/101) parece estar indo por um caminho melhor, mas ainda não sei se é o ideal, ele respondeu em cima do que tinha ali.

Comment: @bigown É verdade. Eu também nao sei porque o AO está fazendo dessa maneira. Eu deixei um comentário na minha respsota dizendo que fazer multi-threaded neste cenário acaba por nao trazer muitas vantagens. Foi uma boa respsota a sua

Comment: @BrunoCosta foi o que eu vi mesmo sem conhecer o `CriaAnimal`, por isso ressalvei que não há ganho. Não sei se estão ensinando na faculdade a usar algo para ter prejuízo, acho lamentável. Poderia se dizer que o objetivo é aprender usar *thread*, mas aí seria só pegar um exemplo onde seria bom o seu uso e que *thread* é melhor que `Task`. Esse é um caso que é possível, mas não tenho certeza, que nenhum mecanismo de paralelização seja útil.

Comment: @bigown Sim escrevi errado. Pode ser útil usar o `Parallell.Foreach` por exemplo. O que queria dizer é que ter uma thread por objeto acaba por nao ter vantagens neste caso.

Comment: @bigown, usei o `Dispatcher.invoke` para poder colocar as imagens na tela, pois estava me dando erro de que a Thread não podia acessar outra thread...

Comment: @MeuChapeu esse código todo parece errado. Está misturando o objeto com tela, tudo me parece esquisito. Aí comete-se um erro para consertar outro erro. Nem sei dizer muito porque é uma técnica que não se usa mais e com o agravante de não ser útil.

Comment: @bigown @Bruno Costa, sou leigo nesses assuntos de `Thread`, estou tentando fazer o que foi solicitado pelo professor, porém também não gosto disso, pois cada animal sendo uma thread, e usuario podendo dizer quantos animais ele quiser... se o usuario digitar 1.000 animais, eu terei 1,000 thread em execução...

Comment: @MeuChapeu isso do usuário poder dizer a quantidade é só uma questão de validação de entrada de dados.

Comment: @bigown, isso que está me deixando confuso, por que cada animal tem que ser um objeto implementado como thread, porém tenho que mostrar na tela esses animais se movimentando...

Comment: A solução parece ser outra, mas aí precisaria de um contexto maior, sem correr o risco de ser ampla :)

Comment: O trabalho é pra ser uma espécie de jogo, porém está misturando muitas coisas na minha opinião...

Comment: @MeuChapeu Em vez de fazer o que lhe foi pedido, voce pode fazer de forma diferente e explicar ao seu professor por que optou por fazer dessa forma. Tente ver questoes relacionadas a threads e perceba quais sao os benefícios que elas podem trazer, assim como os problemas. O bigown deixou algumas perguntas que tocam no assunto. Veja também as perguntas vinculadas a elas. Uma abordagem válida é primeiro fazer só com uma thread mesmo, dai voce pensa numa solucao com muitas.

Answer (score 0):

O que você fez ficou bem confuso, mas o que você quer é impossível.

A classe Thread é marcada com sealed, ou seja não pode ser herdada, portanto não é possível fazer um Animal Thread (Uma criatura bizarra), além de ser impossível a herança múltipla em c#.

Porém você sempre pode fazer um Animal que tem uma Thread (uma agregação), assim pode ter um comportamento dinâmico (acho que é isso que você quer na realidade).

Isso envolve ter um loop na execução da Thread.

```
Cada Thread criada será uma instancia? ou cada Thread apenas está carregando uma referência de uma instancia?
```

A Thread em si, é uma instância de objeto do tipo Thread, como qualquer outro. Quando você emite o Start, ela inicia a execução da função delegada que você designou e ao chegar ao fim ela encerra. Essa execução não bloqueia o seu fluxo de execução (normalmente a Thread da interace, sim a interface roda numa Thread também), pois, você já deve saber, a Thread é escalonada e executada em "paralelo" (ou com divisão de tempo, ou realmente paralelo se você tiver múltiplos núcleos de processador).

```
2 - Imaginemos que a classe Animal tem uma propriedade vida, e quando a vida chegar a 0 o Animal deixa de existir ou seja minha instancia/thread são finalizadas/destruídas, como implementar isso?
```

A função delegada deve ser algo do tipo:

```
private void LoopAnimal()
{
  while(estaVivo)
  {
    //Executar ações do Animal, detectar colisões, implementar comportamentos etc..
    ExecutarComportamentoDoAnimal();
    if(Vida == 0)
      estaVivo = false;
    //Para você não consumir todo o processador deve esperar algum tempo entre cada iteração, o sistema operacional agenda o retorno a essa tarefa, isso não tem muito boa precisão, se você precisa de alta precisão no tempo pesquise por Multimedia Timer, evite bloquear a Thread pois seu processador vai a 100%
    Thread.Sleep(100);
  }
  //Aqui você pode emitir um evento sinalizando que a Thread terminou, isso é necessário pois a Thread não tem um evento que sinaliza o fim (algo do tipo Thread.Exited)
  AnimalMorreu();
}
```

Você pode também utilizar Task, o conceito é +/- o mesmo, mas internamente ela tem uma Thread (que é o elemento mais baixo nível de paralelismo).